# SVN: last committed revision of sparcely populated svn checkout

Tags: svn

I checked out only some files/folders from svn trunk. I want to know svn version number of this checkout (to be used by automated build).
Now, if a file that's part of my sparce checkout gets modifies and I do svn update, then svn info reports new svn version number, even though not a single file was modified in my source tree. So, my goal is to get the svn number of the last updated file in my local checkout.

The only tool that seems to do exactly what I want is SubWCRev.exe which is part of Tortoise SVN:

> ```
> Last committed at revision 40716
> Updated to revision 40719
> ```

That 40716 is the revision number of the last modified file in my local checkout tree. Basically, it means that if I do the same sparse svn update to 40716, 40717, 40718 or 40719 I'll have exactly the same source tree (which essentially should produce the same build output on my buildserver).

What I'm looking for is a tool that's part of standard svn distribution, that can be used on any install of svn client.

Comment: You could write a script that runs `svn info` on each of the items you have cherry-picked, and use the maximum value of `Last Changed Rev`?

Comment: @AndersLindahl looks like it would give expected result, however, I would avoid doing so, since it's difficult to do it right. Sometime we add extra folders to the checkout and that script would have to be updated. Also, I checkout some folders that a few levels deep and I can't simply check last revision of parent folder (which would bring me back to original problem).